# Not booting from Hard Drive

Tags: windows-xp, boot, bios

I have just installed windows XP on my P4 system,

I have changed boot priority to my hard drive

but whenever I try to reboot, it automatically search for CD, if any CD is there, then its OK otherwise it gives an error, reboot and insert media

How can I change the boot priority besides that ??

Thanks

Comment: Which BIOS is it? Can you provide some snapshots of the BIOS screens where you changed the boot device priority?

Comment: Did you remember to save the changes in BIOS. Some BIOS's have two boot priority lists, one for HDD and one general boot list. Make sure you changed the latter one.

Comment: **Change the boot order.**

Comment: @Ramhound I have changed the boot order

Comment: @Martin I have saved the boot priority for general boot list

Comment: @lord_linus - If your computer is trying to boot from a optical media drive that means your hdd doesn't contain a boot sector.  What I actually suspect is you changed it but didn't save the changes.  I can guarantee that if you disconnect the optical disk drive you will boot ito your operating system.